# Probabilistic distance between two distributions

Tags: probability, distributions

I am working on a project and something struck me, I am not sure if I read anything similar to this during my stat courses in my college, and I think this idea is totally new to me.

Suppose I have a probability distribution p(x) and some (incomplete) data having another probability distribution q(x). I know that as I observe more data points, the distribution q(x) will eventually end up to be the distribution p(x). I observe the data points iteratively, one at each step. Ofcourse, as I observe the data points, my distribution does not stay the same as q(x) and changes. Using this, can I somehow find at each step, the probability of observing a data point between two values a and b where a and b are some constants inside their support?

Any help would be great.

Edit: I do not want to get into measure theoretic discussions, hence I specified some bounds a and b, for which I want to find the probability that my next data point lies in between those bounds. Actually I want to find the probability distribution of where my next data point will lie in the support. Hope it clarifies the doubt.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly do the "a and b" bounds refer to? What exactly you want to lie between the bounds?

Comment: Are you just asking how to find the probability for an observation between $a$ and $b$? In that case, fit any distribution with CDF $F$ and evaluate $F(b)-F(a)$. But that doesn't relate to how you discuss *multiple* distributions, so I suspect I am misunderstanding something...

Comment: @StephanKolassa, yes that is what I precisely want to find, but I do not think fitting "any" distribution would help. I think I need a way to find the CDF $F$

Comment: Finding "the" CDF will be hard, given limited information. The best you can likely do is to pick a reasonable class of distributions (e.g., the normal, or a gamma, or a Poisson, depending on your use case), then fit its parameters based on your observations.

Comment: This sounds like an instance of the gambler’s fallacy, from my reading of it. You know the true distribution p, and you have samples that you use to form q. You’re waiting for new samples to “fill in the gaps” for q to match p.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy, huh, that's a nice way to look at it. Any ideas how should I move forward?

Comment: A there is a theorem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko%E2%80%93Cantelli_theorem that shows that KS distance converges to 0 almost surely. Might help you make progress.